# Endless loop when printing specific line from document

Tags: c, file, line

I need to print the third line of a document.

My code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE * dat=NULL;
    char linija[255];
    char linija2[255];
    dat = fopen("ulaz.txt", "r");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
            if ( i = 2 )
            {
                fgets(linija2, 255, dat);
                printf("Vrednost 3 linije iz datoteke ulaz.txt je:\n\n%s\n", linija);
            }
            fgets(linija, 255, dat);

    }
return 0;
}
```

Instead of getting 3rd line, I get a non-sense endless loop in console.

Any sugestions?

Comment: You're endlessly assigning i = 2.

Comment: To clarify the previous comment: `i = 1` is an assignment, not a comparison. Comparison done with `==`.

Comment: And when he fixes that it still won't work because he won't be reading the first two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
FILE * dat=NULL;
char linija[255];

dat = fopen("ulaz.txt", "r");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   fgets(linija, 255, dat);
   if ( i == 2 )
   {
      printf("Vrednost 3 linije iz datoteke ulaz.txt je:\n\n%s\n", linija);
      return;
   }
}
```

This will print the 3rd line of your file.

Disclaimer: this is non tested, non error checking and incomplete code just to give an idea.

Comment: Thanks now i see how stupid mistakes i had done. = (giving valye), and I made mistake with sevond gets. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here, do it like this. Read each line, then on the third line print it and you're done. There's no need to read all 10. And when you open a file, you need to close it. Don't just assume the operating system will clean up your messes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    fgets(linija, 255, dat);
    if ( i == 2 )
    {
        printf("Vrednost 3 linije iz datoteke ulaz.txt je:\n\n%s\n", linija);
    }
}
fclose(dat);
```